# Find a file in folder from a variable

Tags: php

I can't figure this out. I have a folder with X number of PDF files and then I have a product display page where I want my PHP to find a PDF file from the product number being displayed.

F.x. a product called RT 856 - there I want it to find the file that have RT856 in the filename like this: `RT850-RT855-RT857-RT856-RT858.pdf`

Put it in a more simple way I want it to search in the filename and open the file that have the productnumber in the file name.

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: is your folder in same directory as project?

Comment: try to use $files = glob("path/to/directory/*find*.{pdf}", GLOB_BRACE); replace "find" in pattern what you need to search

Comment: @sanj - Wohoo! Simplicity is sometimes better! :) This works! Would you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = glob("path/to/directory/*find*.{pdf}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

replace "find" in pattern what you need to search

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Glob**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) php function. That will help you.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

**Other Way**

```
<?php

    if ($handle = opendir('/~path_to_directory/'))
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                $page_name = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, "."));
                echo $page_name . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.')) as $filename) {
  $names = explode('-', $filename);
  foreach ($names as $name) {
    if (strpos($name, $name_to_find)) {
      echo 'exists';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```